# Implementing a framework inside stencil webcomponent

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, stenciljs

I am using Stencil.js (typescript) for a project. I need to implement this [selectbox](https://github.com/Mobius1/Selectr).

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, h, JSX, Prop, Element } from '@stencil/core';
import Selectr from 'mobius1-selectr';

@Component({
   tag: 'bldc-selectbox',
   styleUrl: 'bldc-selectbox.scss',
   shadow: true
})
export class BldcSelectbox {

   @Element() el: HTMLElement;


   componentDidLoad() {
            //init selectbox 
            new Selectr(this.el.shadowRoot.querySelector('#mySelect') as HTMLOptionElement, {// document.getElementById('mySelect'), {
               searchable: true,
               width: 300
            });
   }  



   render(): JSX.Element {
      return <div>
         <section>
            <select id="mySelect">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
         </section>

      </div>
   }
}
```

Please checkout the image with the result. It does show up, but it does nothing when I click on it.

[image]

Update 1:
I just found out that it does work without the CSS styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That select box plugin does not support Shadow DOM. The problem is [on this line](https://github.com/Mobius1/Selectr/blob/master/src/selectr.js#L278):

```js
if (!this.container.contains(target) && (this.opened || util.hasClass(this.container, "notice"))) {
    this.close();
}
```

Since you're using Shadow DOM, the `target` of this `click` event will be your `bldc-selectbox` element because of [Event Retargeting](https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-events) which means `this.container.contains(target)` will return `false` and the dropdown will close right after it is displayed.

> Events that happen in shadow DOM have the host element as the target, when caught outside of the component.

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/Mobius1/Selectr/issues/104) about using it inside a Shadow DOM which hasn't received any updates since February 2019.

The quickest way to make it work is to disable Shadow DOM on your component. Otherwise `selectr` will need to be updated to support Shadow DOM.